# How to solve error related to Gradle project sync failed, Error: Stub?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, stub

I am beginner for android studio, Android studio work properly but I try to add org.apache.http.legacy file after that I faced a problem related to Gradle project sync failed, Error Stub! I fully uninstalled Android Studio and reinstall it but face same problem. I cannot edit or debug also.

For more detail please find attached image.
[image]

If you need other detail please tell me.

SDK also not work properly. Give bellow error.

> Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
>
> Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>
> Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
>
> Done loading packages.
>
> Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
>
> Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason:
>   Stub!
>
> Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>
> Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
>
> Failed to fetch URL
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml, reason:
>   Runtime Stub!
>
> Done loading packages.

I also uninstall fully Android Studio and reinstall with all new setting but still problem is not solved.

-Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem to fully uninstall Android Studio and install again with permission of Administration, without permission sdk cannot store on right place that's way problem is occur. When you start first time Android studio, right click on it and choose run as administrator.